# How to prevent IOS concurrent NSOperation from running on main thread

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am writing an application that periodically fetches data from a web server using ASI HTTP and then processes that data to display something relevant to the user on the UI. The data is retrieved from different requests on a single server. The data itself needs to be processed in a specific order. One of the blocks of data is much bigger than the other ones.

In order not to lock the UI while the data is being processed, I have tried to use the `NSOperationQueue` to run the data processing on different threads. This works fine about 90% of the times. However, in the remaining 10% of the time, the biggest block of data is being processed on the main thread, which cause the UI to block for 1-2 seconds. The application contains two MKMapViews in different tabs. When both MKMapViews tabs are loaded the percentage of time the biggest block of data is being processed on the main thread increases  above 50% (which seems to point to the assumption that this happens when there is more concurrent activity).

Is there a way to prevent the `NSOperationQueue` to run code on the main thread?

I have tried to play with the `NSOperationQueue` `–setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:`, increasing and decreasing it but there was no real change on the issue.

This is the code that starts the periodic refresh:

```
- (void)refreshAll{    

    // Create Operations
    ServerRefreshOperation * smallDataProcessor1Op = [[ServerRefreshOperation alloc] initWithDelegate:_smallDataProcessor1];
    ServerRefreshOperation * smallDataProcessor2Op = [[ServerRefreshOperation alloc] initWithDelegate:_smallDataProcessor2];
    ServerRefreshOperation * smallDataProcessor3Op = [[ServerRefreshOperation alloc] initWithDelegate:_smallDataProcessor3];
    ServerRefreshOperation * smallDataProcessor4Op = [[ServerRefreshOperation alloc] initWithDelegate:_smallDataProcessor4];
    ServerRefreshOperation * smallDataProcessor5Op = [[ServerRefreshOperation alloc] initWithDelegate:_smallDataProcessor5];
    ServerRefreshOperation * hugeDataProcessorOp = [[ServerRefreshOperation alloc] initWithDelegate:_hugeDataProcessor];

    // Create dependency graph (for response processing)
    [HugeDataProcessorOp addDependency:smallDataProcessor4Op.operation];
    [smallDataProcessor5Op addDependency:smallDataProcessor4Op.operation];
    [smallDataProcessor4Op addDependency:smallDataProcessor3Op.operation];
    [smallDataProcessor4Op addDependency:smallDataProcessor2Op.operation];
    [smallDataProcessor4Op addDependency:smallDataProcessor1Op.operation];

    // Start be sending all requests to server (startAsynchronous directly calls the ASIHTTPRequest startAsynchronous method)
    [smallDataProcessor1Op startAsynchronous];
    [smallDataProcessor2Op startAsynchronous];
    [smallDataProcessor3Op startAsynchronous];
    [smallDataProcessor4Op startAsynchronous];
    [smallDataProcessor5Op startAsynchronous];
    [hugeDataProcessorOp startAsynchronous];
}
```

This is the code that sets the ASI HTTP completion block that starts the data processing:

```
[_request setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self.delegate setResponseString:_request.responseString];
    [[MyModel queue] addOperation:operation]; // operation is a NSInvocationOperation that calls the delegate parse method
}];
```

I have added this block of code in all NSInvocationOperation Invoked method at the entry point:

```
if([NSThread isMainThread]){
    NSLog(@"****************************Running <operation x> on Main thread");
}
```

The line is printed every time the UI freezes. This shows that the whole operation is run on the main thread. It is actually always the `hugeDataProcessorOp` that is run on the main thread. I assume that this is because it is the operation that always receives its answer last from the server.

Comment: None of these operations by themselves will run on the main thread, if you use an NSOperationQueue that's not the main queue. What's probably happening is that within this operation are either blocks being dispatched synchronously onto the main queue or methods being called via `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` with `waitUntilDone` being set to YES. These sections of code will block the main thread until they are completed, even if your operation was running on a background thread. Look for something like that within your operation code.

Comment: @Brad Larson I have been using my own queue, not the main queue. There are only few sections being dispatched in the main thread using performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: and I made sure that waitUntilDone was set to NO. Actually, using breakpoints, I see that the hugeDataProcessorOp sometimes runs in the Main Thread. It is like if the system had only 4-5 background threads available and was choosing to use the Main thread when it is  unused and all the other threads are used.

Comment: Thinking about it, you wouldn't need to be using a synchronous dispatch or setting `waitUntilDone` to YES to see an impact on the main thread from these operations. Any computation or other time-consuming action they dump off on the main thread could block the main thread, even if these operations are not blocked waiting on the completion of these actions. When you set the breakpoints in your operations that seem to indicate they're running on the main thread, are you sure the portion of code you're breaking on isn't wrapped in something that calls back to the main thread?

Comment: @Brad Larson I added a block of code at the entry point of all the operations being called. It is really from the entry point that the operation runs on the main thread. I edited the post to show the block of code.

Comment: By "at the entry point", do you mean right after the start of the `-main` method for your NSOperation subclass? Also, what does the `-startAsynchronous` method do in the above code? Now that I look at it, you aren't actually adding hugeDataProcessorOp and the other operations to a queue anywhere. Is that done within `-startAsynchronous`?

Comment: @Brad Larson My operation is a NSInvocationOperation. The "entry point" is the first line of the selector being invoked. The -startAsynchronous method directly calls the ASIHTTPRequest -startAsynchronous method. The hugeDataProcessorOp and other operations are added in an operation queue in the ASIHTTPRequest completionBlock callback (this part of code is in the original post).

Comment: @Brad Larson This whole thing was a coding error. The "entry point" was being called directly by some old code that had not been removed completely when I implemented my operation queue. Your comments helped me look at the good place in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much investigation in my own code, I can confirm that this was a coding error.

There was an old call remaining that did not go through the NSInvocationOperation but was calling the selector that NSInvocationOperation should have called directly (therefore not using the concurrent `NSOperationQueue`.

This means that the `NSOperationQueue` DOES NOT use the main thread (except if it is the one retrieved by `+mainQueue`).

Comment: Good to hear. I would've been seriously worried if NSOperations were randomly being executed on the main thread. That would have been quite the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Override [`isConcurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/isConcurrent) on your NSOperation and return `YES`. According to the documentation this will cause your NSOperation to be run asynchronously.

Comment: No, that's not right. The `isConcurrent` property is only useful if you are running the operations yourself, without a queue: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW9 . You don't want to use that here.

Comment: My operation does run concurrently. The issue is that while some operations are run on background threads, some are run on the Main Thread.  It is like if the system had only 4-5 background threads available and was choosing to use the Main thread when it is unused and all the other threads are used.